# stop the debugger in the next statment

Tags: c#, .net

I need a code that on a will enter into a the called function and than pause the debugger

for example

calling `DEBUG(Foo())` will call the function foo and only than break.

is this possible?

I am aware of `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` but I want to save myself doing step into all the time

example for my problem:

```
   foreach (Action item in collection)
        {
            if (IsDebug && System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); <----- stops here
                item.Invoke()
            }
        }
```

this code stops before the call to `item.Invoke()` I want it to stop inside it.

Comment: breakpoint dude.. put a breakpoint.

Comment: Is it required only for you current debug session? If yes then you could use Function Breakpoint : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15d1wtaf(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: this is a part of integration testing tool. and is required permenetly. 
I have hundreds of functions in an array. and I don't want to add debugger.break to all of them

Comment: @KenKin Got You, Good Year, Great Yoda, and also my name initials ;)

Comment: They killing you at Transway... ok.. I understand what you need.. maybe this can help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD

Comment: 1. yes they are killing us here please help me we score 3 at joel test I MUST GET OUT OF HERE!!!

2. this one isn't a must I just thought to save myself lots of unnessesey F11 presses.

3. thanks for the link I was looking for a good examplanation of how to impliment AOP by myself.

Comment: @NahumLitvin np :) don't be so worry about the joel test - I had worked in our beloved Israel with companies who managed to score below zero on it. here is example to how this even possible: "Do you use source control?" CTO answer: "yes, everyone in the team has source safe installed locally in his machine"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

- Put a breakpoing on `item.Invoke()` and use "Step into" keyboard shortcut <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Add `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute to Foo, so that debugger would not go in to it.
- Just split your code into two lines and put a breakpoint on the second:

  ```
  var result = Foo();
  DEBUG(result);
  ```